# How to check during "pre_get_posts" if WP performing default query for specific custom template?

Tags: plugin-development, templates, rss, pre-get-posts

I want to modify default query for custom RSS template loaded by plugin that i'am writing right now. What is the best way to check - in function hooked to "pre_get_posts" - if default query for my specific custom teplate is about to be performed, so i can modify it?

**Answer:**

It was much easier than i thought. When using approach suggested in [Controlling and customising RSS feeds in WordPress](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/controlling_and_customising_rss_feeds_in_wordpress/) where you can see something like this in rewrites `index.php?feed=custom_feed` you simply check query vars, so your actions looks like that:

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'gs_gscrf_pre_get_posts');
    function gs_gscrf_pre_get_posts($query) {
        if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['feed'] == 'custom_feed') {
        // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Check [Rarst explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102885/24610), if you want to know why i have to use `query_vars`and cannot check for template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe the timing would not quite work. During WP core load:

1. main query is created and processed into query variables (with `pre_get_posts` being one of the hooks able to influence the results)
2. then `template-loader.php` uses conditionals (dependent on those query variables) to determine template to use

So at the point of `pre_get_posts` you cannot technically check for template choice, because that is not happened yet. However what you can check for - is query variables are those that correspond with that template being chosen down the road. Which is practically quite close.

Comment: I found same solution in meantime, but thanks anyway for clarification & I ofc. accept you explanation. Thanks for the second time. :)